# Why is TestNG seeing my package but not my class?

Tags: java, classpath, testng

When I run (Windows 7 command line):

C:\rest-app\src\main\java\com\mycompany\app\Test>java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

I get:

===============================================

Suite1
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

===============================================

This is when my testng.xml file looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >
<test name="SandBoxTests"   >
    <packages>
        <package name="com.mycompany.app.Test" />
    </packages>
</test>
</suite>
```

I have three tests in my class in that package.

When I change my testng.xml file to be:

```
<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >
<test name="SandBoxTests"   >
    <classes>
        <class name="com.mycompany.app.Test.SandBoxTests">
            <methods>
                <include name="com.mycompany.app.Test.SandBoxTests.TestA"/>
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
 </test>
</suite>
```

I get the response:

[TestNG] [ERROR]
Cannot find class in classpath: com.mycompany.app.Test.SandBoxTests

My classpath looks like:

C:\rest-app\lib\ *;C:\rest-app\src\main\java\com\mycompany\app\Test\ *

The first directory points to all of my included .jar files, including testng and the last directory includes the location of the class file from which I'm trying to run my tests. my testng.xml file is there as well.

So how is it that TestNG appears to find my package just fine, but fails to see my class?

My code is:

```
package com.mycompany.app.Test;

import com.mycompany.app.RestMethods;
import com.mycompany.app.Test.TestObjects.AutoCompleteList;
import com.mycompany.app.Test.TestObjects.AutocompleteItem;
import com.mycompany.app.Test.TestObjects.Title;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;


public class SandBoxTests
```

{
    ...

```
@BeforeClass
public void SetupSandBoxTests() throws Exception
{

}

@Test
public void TestA() throws Exception
{
    ...
}

...
}
```

EDIT:  I updated my classpath to include the location of the compiled source file that has my TestNG tests and also included the root of the path which contains my testng.xml file, but nothing has changed.  I added:

C:\rest-app\out\production\Main\ *;C:\rest-app\out\production\Main\com\homeaway\app\Test\ *

EDIT 10/25: Maven now builds and executes the tests correctly, but I still am unable to get testng to execute from the command line.  In order to get Maven to run my tests I had to use

```
<includes>
    <include>**/*.java</include>
</includes>
```

instead of:

```
<suiteXmlFiles>
    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
</suiteXmlFiles>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39942523/unable-to-read-methods-on-class-testng/40329265#40329265

Answer (score 0):

Your classpath should point to where the packages start, not the java-files themselves.

Move your testng.xml to src/main/java and use this classpath:

C:\rest-app\lib*;C:\rest-app\src\main\java\

EDIT:
I realized that you're actually trying to run the test suite directly. This needs to be done on the compiled test classes - your classpath should point to the binaries.

However, this is all handled by maven for you, if you use the default setup:

```
src/main/java/ <- your java code
src/test/java/ <- your test code where test-classes are named *Test.java
```

In your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.3.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

See: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html

Comment: I updated my classpath and moved my testng.xml file as suggested but receive the same error.  The contents of my xml file are the same.

Comment: Oy - my bad. When you run the tests, you'll want to run them on the compiled classes, not the java-file itself.

Comment: I wondered about that.  My IDE appears to run them without compiling.  I updated my classpath in my answer, but still the same problem.  I thought \* said to look in all paths below?

Answer (score 0):

Your source file might not get compiled by your project. Are you using maven to execute the test ??

Comment: I will be using Maven in a little bit once I figure that whole mess out but for now, no, I'm not using it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >
<test name="SandBoxTests"   >
    <classes>
        <class name="com.mycompany.app.Test.SandBoxTests">
            <methods>
                <include name="TestA"/>
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
 </test>
</suite>
```

I think under method it is not searching for the whole class path. i didnt try this out . but this should work

Comment: I tried this and received the error I put in my comments to niharika_neos response.  At least its a different error..  progress perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

I think your classpath is incorrect.  A class path entry that contains * will not match class files.  You can refer to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) to get some idea.
If your classes lie in `C:\rest-app\out\production\Main\com\homeaway\app\Test\`, then
`com\urco\app\Test` is part of the package name, so I think you should put only C:\rest-app\out\production\Main\ in your classpath.

Hope that helps..

Comment: I modified my classpath accordingly and implemented the XML change from the comment below and now receive:[TestNG] [ERROR]
Cannot instantiate class com.homeaway.app.SandBoxTestsIT