# Unable to read methods on class - TestNG

Tags: java, jenkins, testng

I have created a simple selenium project(not maven) using testng framework and trying to integrate it with Jenkins.
While running the testrunner.bat file through Jenkins, it gives me below warning on console and not able to execute my test cases.

C:\Users\Shipra Parihar\testMavenProject\Test_Automation_Framework>testrunner.bat

C:\Users\Shipra Parihar\testMavenProject\Test_Automation_Framework>java -cp bin;lib/* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml 
[TestNGClassFinder] Warning: Can't link and determine methods of class com.qa.tests.LoginTest
[[TestNGClassFinder]] Unable to read methods on class com.qa.tests.LoginTest - unable to resolve class reference org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
[TestNGClassFinder] Warning: Can't link and determine methods of class com.qa.tests.SearchTest
[[TestNGClassFinder]] Unable to read methods on class com.qa.tests.SearchTest - unable to resolve class reference org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
[TestNGClassFinder] Warning: Can't link and determine methods of class com.qa.tests.ListingPageTest
[[TestNGClassFinder]] Unable to read methods on class com.qa.tests.ListingPageTest - unable to resolve class reference org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
[TestNGClassFinder] Warning: Can't link and determine methods of class com.qa.tests.DetailpageTest
[[TestNGClassFinder]] Unable to read methods on class com.qa.tests.DetailpageTest - unable to resolve class reference org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
[TestNGClassFinder] Warning: Can't link and determine methods of class com.qa.tests.PaymentpageTest
[[TestNGClassFinder]] Unable to read methods on class com.qa.tests.PaymentpageTest - unable to resolve class reference org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\Shipra Parihar\testMavenProject\Test_Automation_Framework\testng.xml

===============================================
Suite

## Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

Please provide me solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 

Please review [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question. Post the code you have tried and the content of testrunner.bat. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and this is the way I solved it.
I put all the .jar file I need to a folder and add to build path of project.
Then I run the following command line:

```
java -cp "[compile folder]";"[JAR folder]\*" org.testng.TestNG [xml file]
```

For example

```
java -cp "D:\Automations\Selenium\Workspace\SimpleTest\bin";"D:\Automations\Selenium\Workspace\SimpleTest\JAR File\*" org.testng.TestNG runTest.xml
```

Hope it helpful for you.